# System.Threading.Tasks not obeying start rules?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

ReWrite: I have stripped the question down to contain the example code instead of a link to it and the results and question as the surrounding information seemed to be causing confusion.

Question: Why do tasks seem to start with out being started?

This is a piece of sample code from the [Microsoft Website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) on tasks. It is described as creating an unstarted task, creating a second started task and waiting for it to complete, then starting the first task and finally starting a third task synchronously in the main thread.

Here is an uncommented version of the sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class StartNewDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Action<object> action = (object obj) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task={0}, obj={1}, Thread={2}", Task.CurrentId, obj.ToString(), Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        };

        Task t1 = new Task(action, "alpha");

        Task t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(action, "beta");

        t2.Wait();

        t1.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("t1 has been launched. (Main Thread={0})", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        t1.Wait();

        Task t3 = new Task(action, "gamma");

        t3.RunSynchronously();

        t3.Wait();
    }
}
```

Here are the results:

```
Task=1, obj=beta, Thread=3
t1 has been launched. (Main Thread=1)
Task=2, obj=alpha, Thread=3
Task=3, obj=gamma, Thread=1
```

From the description task 1, which is Beta, should be ran only after task 2 has completed so the main thread can progress. This does not seem to be the case from this output. I also ran a second test run where I put a display of the tick counts into the action object and received this, confirming that Task1 is indeed starting before Task2 is completed.

```
Task=1, obj=beta, Thread=3 (634529151744201906)
t1 has been launched. (Main Thread=1)
Task=2, obj=alpha, Thread=3 (634529151744221908)
Task=3, obj=gamma, Thread=1 (634529151744221908)
```

I am not trying to do anything fancy here, I am simply looking for an explanation as to why Task1 (obj=beta) is apparently executing before it is given the instruction to do so.

Comment: "The software I am working on requires careful control over how many or which cores are lit up during specific stages in the work flow" - could you explain why? If code is suitable for multi-threading, why would it need a specific core count?

Comment: Removed the line from the question as it had nothing to really do with the question. Gave too much background information I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Task=1, obj=beta, Thread=3
```

Task=1 is slightly misleading here, as this is actually t2 in the sample code.  You can see this because 'beta' is present.  It is started and completed before running t1.

```
t1 has been launched. (Main Thread=1)
Task=2, obj=alpha, Thread=3
```

This is t1 (with Id 2).

```
Task=3, obj=gamma, Thread=1
```

This is t3.

Comment: I am a fool and did not notice that, thank you. I was misreading the results! Thank you very much!

Comment: @James, one interesting result from this is that the Task Id is apparently set when the Task is scheduled and not when it is constructed.

Comment: Nice spot, I would give you a +2 if I could as that saved me from relying on the IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Threads or assignment of `Task`s to threads aren't guaranteed (i.e. non-deterministic) to be in order without some form of synchronization.

Comment: So a task can start then with out having .Start() called on it or being created by .StartNew() from the factory?

Comment: Ah, that is my question though, why do tasks not seem to obey starting until told to do so.

Comment: have you debugged this line by line?

Comment: I rewrote the question to be more exact with a bit more of the debugging I had done to try to figure this out, but Dan has shown what I was misinterpreting. Thank you in any case.

Answer (score 1):

When you start a task, it may not execute immediately (if there isn't a free thread pool thread). But tasks never start by themselves. And the output you observed is correct.

The code executes like this:

- `t1` (`alpha`) is created, but not executed
- `t2` (`beta`) is created, started, prints to console (apparently with `TaskId == 1`) and is waited upon
- `t1` (`alpha`) is started, apparently with `TaskId == 2`
- notification about starting `t1` is printed
- `t1` (`alpha`) prints to the console and is waited upon
- the rest should be obvious

Comment: +1 for a good answer, and an earlier answer. Due to odd ordering of responses though I read Dan's first and marked it as the answer.

Comment: @James, answers with the same score are ordered randomly. And I think you can change your mind regarding what is the accepted answer.